# Asking about native running software, question closed, no idea why

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I'm trying to understand why my question about native running software was closed. A friend said this would be the site for me to ask my question.

[What does it mean for software to run natively?](https://superuser.com/questions/583337/what-does-it-mean-for-software-to-run-natively)

Why wouldn't a vocabulary question like this be allowed?

Answers like the ones received can't be found as concisely elsewhere or with the interaction Stack Exchange allows.

Comment: I admit, the question title made me think of the difference between running a "program" under either an "operating system" or on the processor itself (e.g. direct hardware access).

Answer (score 5):

The question

- shows no sign that any research was done
- lacks any context or background
- reads like it was thrown onto the site haphazardly trying to gather as many question marks as possible
- strings together streams of consciousness

As a result the answers yielded are long winded and add as much guesswork as there are paragraphs to work out your situation, trying to cover every tangent possible as the question has started.

Answer (score 3):

It was closed probably because people felt this is a question that can be answered by spending 5 minutes on google. It was also not very well written and slightly hard to understand.

The question is both on topic and interesting enough to have collected some popular and good answers though. I have edited it to make it clearer and have nominated for reopening.